# Laravel Query, Group and counting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have a table scheme of

`| playerID | team | gameResult | pickOrder |`

I have hundreds of results and I am trying to identify the following groupbed by `playerID`.

I want to count how many times `gameResult` is a `Win` or a `Loss` only when `pickOrder` value is `0`. I would like to display it in an array format such as

```
array(
  'PlayerID' => '2837192',
    'data' => array(
       'win' => '9',
       'Loss' => '3'
      )
   ),
   ...
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
$results = DB::table('players')
               ->select(DB::raw("playerID"),
                        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 END) AS win_cnt"),
                        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' THEN 1 END) AS loss_cnt"))
               ->where('pickOrder', '=', 0)
               ->groupBy('playerID')
               ->get();
```

The above Laravel code would correspond to the following raw MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    playerID,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 END) AS win_cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' THEN 1 END) AS loss_cnt
FROM players
WHERE pickOrder = 0
GROUP BY
    playerId;
```

Comment: I don'r know why unfortunately, though I can tell you everything in the raw MySQL query should be a number.  You might have to do a cast from your PHP code.